# Option to Embed 'Video from SharePoint' in PowerPoint Presentation missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, video, powerpoint

We are storing videos on SharePoint Online (in an Asset Library) and would like to embed them in a PowerPoint presentation.

We expect to be able to use the 'Insert Online Video' option in PowerPoint 2016 to do this, but for almost all of our users this does not work: there is simply no option to select 'Video from SharePoint', see this screenshot (in Dutch):

[image]

What we would expect to see is the following (this is working for one of our users, even though he also uses Windows 10 and PowerPoint 2016, just like our other users:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To insert video in PowerPoint from your SharePoint or OneDrive online storage, you should sign in with your Microsoft account.

Refer to: https://www.teachucomp.com/insert-video-in-powerpoint-instructions/

Comment: do I understand correctly that inserting video is not possible when you are logged in with an Office 365 (Azure AD) account? Or does that also count as  a Microsoft account?

Comment: I'm logged into my Microsoft account, but no option to insert from OneDrive or SharePoint exists in PowerPoint 2016.